# unable to use Push notifications in window store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I'm new to windows 8 app development. I'm using XAML and C# for it. I have a scenario where i'm facing loads of difficulties. Okay the scenario is
   I want my app to give notifications even if the app is in closed state (like push notifications). In my back end i'm running a job which updates the values in the Microsoft SQL server database ( while the update may result in some change in value or may not). If the value/values in the database changes i want my app to give notification of that when it is running and even if it is closed. Any link, solution, anything is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at azure mobile services:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply Alexander. I looked into it. The problem is that my database is not on Azure. Do I need to have my database on cloud as well. I don't think its possible to run sql jobs on cloud.

Comment: No, you don't have to use sql azure. Here's a great getting started sample: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-push-dotnet/?fb=de-de